# Birt Engine and Apache poi combination compatible

Tags: java, apache-poi, birt, birt-emitter

I am writing a java code that will generate excel `.xlsx` file format. Using `apache poi v5.0` and birt
engine runtime `v4.3.0`. Looks like `poi` doesn't have `setBoldweight()` method. Is this version dependency error or how to I solve this. Is there any other alternative to solve this?. Please help.

If it is version dependency error. Which version of birt report is compatible with `apache-poi 5`?.

It give me this error

```
ERROR org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngine:2374 - Error happened while running the report.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBoldweight(S)V
    at uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.FontManager.createFont(FontManager.java:165)
    at uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.FontManager.getFont(FontManager.java:230)
    at uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.StyleManager.createStyle(StyleManager.java:169)
    at uk.co.spudsoft.birt.emitters.excel.StyleManager.getStyle(StyleManager.java:217)
....
```

This is my code

```
IRunAndRenderTask task=null;
birtEngine = MSBirtEngine.getBirtEngine(null);
task = birtEngine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;

if("xlsx".equals(format)){
    EXCELRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();
    options.setOutputFormat(format);
    ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    options.setOutputStream(ous);
    task.setRenderOption(options);
}

task.run();
...
```